# Subscript directly underneath operator, without having superscript directly above operator

Tags: math-mode

I would like to use the minimum operator in latex, with the subscript directly below the minimum operator but without having the superscript directly above the minimum operator. Right now I got

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[\min^{+}_{j \in \mathcal{A}^{C}}\]
\end{document}
```

Which results in

[image: Result]
              ,whereas I would like to end up having 
[image]

Does anyone know how to do this?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `{\min_{...}}^+`

Comment: "Which results in" that is not the output I get on my end. WHen I compiled you code, I get this ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/UITCZ.png)  How did you get the output above?

Comment: @Nasser, I have no idea how my output can be different than yours, but David's comment helped me get the desired output :)

Comment: @Nasser is correct that the posted image is not generated by the posted code (Nordin you should fix that) the image shows display math so `\[..\]` not `$...$`

Comment: "I have no idea how my output can be different than yours" I also have no idea.

Answer (score 1):

One of these three perhaps

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
{\min_{j \in \mathcal{A}^{C}}}^{+}
\quad
\mathop{{\min}^{+}}_{j \in \mathcal{A}^{C}}
\quad
{\min_{\mathclap{j \in \mathcal{A}^{C}}}}^{+}
\]
\end{document}
```

The first places a + on a mathord constructed from min and the subscript (note the construct will then be a mathord in relation to any following terms, which may or may not be the spacing that you want)

The second is a mathop constructed from min+ so gets the limits spacing for the subscript, and mathop space for any following terms. Note that unlike the other two, this one centres the subscript on min+ not on min.

The third is like the first but hides the width of the subscript which gives tighter spacing for the + (but fir very large subscripts has the danger that it may over-print adjacent terms with no warning.

Comment: In Exercise 18.44 of _The TeXbook_ Knuth endorses the second solution, and shows how to center the subscript on `\min` instead of on `{\min}^{+}` (the code should adapted to LaTeX, of course).